# Serving Website With Nginx on Raspberry Pi Alongside Octoprint

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, nginx-config, octoprint

I'm trying to get my website up on my raspberry pi right now and I ran into some issues with Octoprint getting in the way.  I had my website served using nginx on a different sd card that **didn't** have Octoprint and it worked just fine. Now when I try to access my website I run into the Octoprint login page.

I suspect that this is due to port 80 already being used by Octoprint but I'm not completely sure since I'm fairly new to this stuff.  I have messed around with the nginx configs but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Also, if you have any suggestions about the security of this setup please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Octoprint on a different port

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30513249)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing running the nginx webserver on the default 80 and 443 port for HTTPS and running octoprint on port 5000, there is no other way to run two servers on the same port.